# Number of permutations for two cards of the same type

Tags: probability

Let's assume I have $4$ cards, of which $1$ is a heart and $3$ are spades. So the total is $4$ and we have $2$ distinct classes. Let's assume the case of a two-fold draw from this set (without replacement). I am interested in the case that both cards will be spades.

I am confused on the following:

It seems that the number of distinct permutations of these $2$ cards is $$\frac{2!}{2!} \cdot 3 \cdot 2=6$$
But I don't understand this. How in general are we considering in such problem the spade drawn from the first pick and the spade drawn from the second pick as different?

Perhaps I am not phrasing my question correctly but I was thinking that if we have $2$ spades there is only $1$ (distinct) permutation. I mean what is the difference between the $2$ spades?

Also, what is the relationship of this number of permutations with the fact that the probability of choosing $2$ spades is $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the selections are made with replacement, there are three spades and one heart available in each draw.  Hence, the probability of selecting two spades with replacement is simply
$$\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{16}$$

**Edit:**  The question has been revised to indicate that the selections are made without replacement.

If the selections are made without replacement, there are still three spades and one heart available for the first draw.  If a spade is selected during the first draw, then there are two spades and one heart available for the second draw, so the probability of drawing two spades without replacement is 
$$\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$$ 
As for the number of distinct permutations of two of the four cards, there are four ways to select the first card and three ways to select the second card, for a total of $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ possible permutations.  Of these, there are three ways to select a spade in the first draw and two ways to select a spade in the second draw given that a spade was selected during the first draw, for a total of $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ ways to select two spades on the first two draws.  Notice that 
$$\frac{3 \cdot 2}{4 \cdot 3} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: We draw 2 distinct cards of same type from 4 though. (And it is without replacement sorry for that. I corrected the original question)